# How to run a TFJob with custom python scheduler

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, scheduler

May I know that anyone created custom scheduler in python that handle the tensorflow jobs pods? I am trying to read add my custom scheduler name in my TFJob yaml file but my scheduler is not able to detect the pending pods of TFJob. Thank you

Any python code of scheduler or changes in code or TFJob deployment changes.